compose-desktop app import error by using vico charts plugin
The import of a specific library (vico) isn't working after implementing into the build.gradle file.The Library is added, but cannot be used. I already used different kotlin, compose or library versions and it did not work for any of these.
build.gradle.kts :
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    // Note, if you develop a library, you should use compose.desktop.common.
    // compose.desktop.currentOs should be used in launcher-sourceSet
    // (in a separate module for demo project and in testMain).
    // With compose.desktop.common you will also lose @Preview functionality
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)

    // For Jetpack Compose.
    implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:compose:2.0.0-alpha.14")

    // For `compose`. Creates a `ChartStyle` based on an M2 Material Theme.
    implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:compose-m2:2.0.0-alpha.14")

    // For `compose`. Creates a `ChartStyle` based on an M3 Material Theme.
    implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:compose-m3:2.0.0-alpha.14")

    // Houses the core logic for charts and other elements. Included in all other modules.
    implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:core:2.0.0-alpha.14")

    // For the view system.
    implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:views:2.0.0-alpha.14")
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "demo"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}


Main.kt :
import androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application

import com.patrykandpatrick.vico // import error

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World!") }

    MaterialTheme {
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}


I want to build a desktop-compose app with the vico charts library. By implementing the library I should be able to use it to create charts.

this lib is for android only, it doesn't support compose desktop. related issue: https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico/issues/244

I think you should use the latest version release is "1.14.0". Could you try to replace "2.0.0-alpha.14" by "1.14.0"
